# Multiple OR statements in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

How can I have multiple OR statements in an SSRS expression? Seems to be giving me an error.

Here is what I have now: `=IIF((Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*A2*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*A3*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*A4*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*B2*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*B3*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*B4*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*C2*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*C3*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*C4*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*D2*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*D3*') or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE '*D4*'), "TOP", "")`

Comment: So which version of ssrs are you *actually* using. You've got 2008, 2012, and 2005 tagged

Comment: "seems"? Either it is, or it isn't... and if it is, what exactly IS the error message?

Comment: Tagged all three for visibility.  @AndrewL.  Using 2008

Comment: @AndrewL. It does, since the answer applies to all 3.  Perhaps you could take your attentions elsewhere if you don't have anything productive to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SSRS use double quote for strings.

Try:

```
 =IIF((Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*A2*") or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*A3*")
or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*A4*") or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*B2*")
or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*B3*") or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*B4*")
or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*C2*") or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*C3*")
or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*C4*") or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*D2*")
or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*D3*") or (Fields!PART.Value LIKE "*D4*"), "TOP", "")
```

Let me know if this helps.